# jquery ui datepicker error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

This is the error message I get when try to implement the datepicker:

Unhandled exception at line 133, column 9 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'

This is the code I have added to the View:

```
   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>`
```

Here is the script:

```
<script>

$(function () {

    $("#model.Date").datepicker();

});
```

This is my first jQuery element so I don't know what I am doing wrong. I don't understand the entire jQuery element process.

Comment: `datepicker()` is not a method in plain jQuery, it is part of jQueryUI, so you need to include `jqueryui.js` in your page.

Comment: Should I just download that package from the NuGet Package manager?

Comment: You could, or you can get it directly from http://jqueryui.com

Comment: I downloaded it from the NuGet package manager and I added a bundle to the `bundleconfig.cs` file. I still get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

`datepicker()` is not a method in plain jQuery. It is part of the jQueryUI library, which you will also need to include in your page:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#model.Date").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

The jQueryUI library can be downloaded from http://jqueryui.com